# How can I see on my iPhone the rails app is running on my mac via Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios-simulator, passenger, iphone

I'm developing a rails app, now I'm working on the CSS specifically for iPhone, on my mac.
I've my app running via Passenger at http://whatever.local

It'd be nice to access via iPhone to the same URL so I can test my CSS quickly. But how?

Thank you,

Leo

Comment: This might sound silly but are you connected to your network through WiFi and not on 3G?

Comment: Yep, same wifi. I fixed that, see below. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically speaking, you'd do this by entering the network IP address of the Mac on the iphone instead of whatever.local.

http://192.168.1.1:3000/posts/ or whatever it may be!

Answer (score 0):

http://192.168.1.1:3000/ (will vary depending on which IP was assigned to which machine.)

Don't forget to check port-forwarding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding). That gave me some problems in the past.